# how to install python interpreter in quiet mode on windows10?

Tags: python-3.x

I don't even know where to start, but I need to somehow install the python interpreter in quiet mode on windows 10, how can I do it? (I suppose I'll have to compile it myself from source, but I would like to be simpler)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Edit

Go to https://www.python.org/ftp/python/3.9.2/

Download python3.x exe file

Run CMD as admin

Change directory to your download folder ( where you downloaded the exe file )

RUn this command

```
python-3.9.x-amd64.exe /quiet InstallAllUsers=1 PrependPath=1
```

Comment: and for python3 is there?

Comment: thank you, it works. And I immediately began to think along a difficult path. the only windows warns that python wants to install and asks for confirmation, can this be bypassed somehow?

Comment: glad it worked. If my answer helped , please accept it as right answer ...can you explain what exactly the confirmation message is ? also make sure you are running the command prompt as admin and add another argument `TargetDir="C:\Python39"` at the end of the command i have posted in answer .